# Need help with derivation of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, standard-deviation

The following is taken from the book "*Mathematical Statistics for Economics and Business*":

> \begin{align*}
> E\left.\left( \left[ Y-h(x) \right]^2\ \right\vert\ x\right)
> =& E\left.\left( \left[\,Y-E(Y|x)+E(Y|x)-h(x)\,\right]^2\ \right\vert\ x\right)\\
> =& E\left( \left.\left[\,Y-E(Y|x)\,\right]^2\ \right\vert\ x\right) + \left(E(Y|x)-h(x)\right)^2\\
> &\text{(by substitution theorem)}.
> \end{align*}

I don't understand this derivation. Please help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $\mathbb{E}[(Y-h(x))^2|x]=\mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|x]+\mathbb{E}[Y|x]-h(x))^2|x]$ (the equality is trivial), and expand the RHS:
$$
\begin{align*}
RHS &= \mathbb{E}\!\left[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|x]+\mathbb{E}[Y|x]-h(x))^2 \ \middle|\ x\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\!\left[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|x])^2+(\mathbb{E}[Y|x]-h(x))^2 + 2(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|x])(\mathbb{E}[Y|x]-h(x)) \ \middle|\ x\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\!\left[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|x])^2 \ \middle|\ x\right]+\mathbb{E}\!\left[(\mathbb{E}[Y|x]-h(x))^2 \ \middle|\ x\right] + 2\mathbb{E}\!\left[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|x])(\mathbb{E}[Y|x]-h(x)) \ \middle|\ x\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\!\left[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|x])^2 \ \middle|\ x\right]+(\mathbb{E}[Y|x]-h(x))^2 + 2\mathbb{E}\!\left[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|x])(\mathbb{E}[Y|x]-h(x)) \ \middle|\ x\right]
\end{align*}
$$
using the linearity of conditional expectations, and for the last equality the fact that $(\mathbb{E}[Y|x]-h(x))^2$ is $x$-measurable.

From there, to get your result, the first two terms being what you want, it only remains to show the third one is $0$. This is the case, since
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\!\left[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|x])(\mathbb{E}[Y|x]-h(x)) \ \middle|\ x\right] 
&= \mathbb{E}\!\left[Y\mathbb{E}[Y|x] - \mathbb{E}[Y|x]^2-Yh(x) + \mathbb{E}[Y|x]h(x) \ \middle|\ x\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\!\left[Y\mathbb{E}[Y|x]  \ \middle|\ x\right] - \mathbb{E}[Y|x]^2-\mathbb{E}\!\left[Yh(x) \ \middle|\ x\right] + \mathbb{E}\!\left[\mathbb{E}[Y|x]h(x) \ \middle|\ x\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[Y|x]\cdot\mathbb{E}\!\left[Y \middle| x\right] - \mathbb{E}[Y|x]^2-h(x) \cdot\mathbb{E}\!\left[Y \middle| x\right] + \mathbb{E}[Y|x]\cdot h(x) \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
$$
using the fact that $h(x)$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y|x]$ are $x$-measurable.

Comment: (as a side note, $x$ being a random variable, it is usually capitalized: $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]$.)

Comment: No, your last equality of the RHS is not right. The second term of the equality is {E[Y(x)]-h(x)}^2, and this is the point I have not understood.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it. It comes from the fact that $(\mathbb{E}[Y|x]-h(x))^2$ is $x$-measurable, and that for any $x$-measurable r.v. $Z$ you have $\mathbb{E}[Z|X]=Z$ (there also was a typo at the very last line of the derivation, before the "$=0$" line).

Answer (score 1):

> Assume that the random variables $Z$ and $T$ are such that $Z$ is measurable with respect to $X$ and $E[T\mid X]=0$. Then $E[(T+Z)^2\mid X]=E[T^2\mid X]+Z^2$.

The result in your question follows, choosing $T=Y-E[Y\mid X]$ (*since then $E[T\mid X]=0$, can you show it?*) and $Z=E[Y\mid X]+h(X)$ (*since then $Z$ is measurable with respect to $X$, can you show it?*).

To prove the assertion recakked above, one expands $(T+Z)^2=T^2+2TZ+Z^2$ and one uses the identities $E[TZ\mid X]=ZE[T\mid X]=0$ and $E[Z^2\mid X]=Z^2$ (*can you show them?*).